# Creating a config file for a website in PHP

Tags: php, html, variables, include

I am creating a website template that will have an index file that will include a phrase from config.php.

Let's say I have a file called config.php with the following code:

```
<?php
$sitename = "Test Site"
?>
```

How would I take $sitename from that config file to an HTML file with the code like this:

```
<?php include 'config.php';
echo "<h1>$sitename</h1>
?>
```

Would this work? If not, how could I fix it?

Comment: Seems like you have all the ingredients necessary for an experiment. What were the results?

Comment: c9.io output this code when I previewed the page: `$sitename ?>`

Comment: Do close out your `<?php` tag properly.

Comment: I did indeed. Just to clarify, I will link the contents of both files. [Index](https://hastebin.com/bemunilato.xml) and here is [Config](https://hastebin.com/aruvidowar.xml)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, logic is correct, but code no.

So.. Replace:

```
<?php
  $sitename = "Test Site";
?>
```

with:

```
<?php 
  include 'config.php';
  echo "<h1>".$sitename."</h1>";
?>
```

Comment: I am using https://c9.io to run my code online, i got this result on index.html: `".$sitename.""; ?>`

Comment: Changing to concatenation from interpolation doesn't really change anything. [PHP strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) are so wildly misunderstood.

Comment: why .html? Use .php file! You can't call php var in .html file!

Comment: I have just switched to a PHP file and I get a blank output

Comment: Can get me list of file in your ftp?
config.php and index.php , are you sure? another ext?

Comment: check my post, if code is correct. Remember close php ( ?> ) and Semicolon ( ; )